# How do I change the font on the bound part of a TextBlock's content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

Given the below TextBlock, how do I make the `SomeString` part of the text **bold**?

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString,StringFormat='{}Row: {0}'}" />
```

ie: If `SomeString = "ABC"` I want the TextBlock to look like this:

> Row: **ABC**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Row:"/>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding SomeString}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I guess this will do what I want. I was hoping to avoid creating multiple TextBlocks though.

Comment: Adding a Label doesn't accomplish anything (besides adding complexity). Just use the StackPanel. And what's up with `DataContext="{Binding}"`? That looks like a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you could format each individual **Run** inside the same TextBlock.

**Through XAML**

```
<TextBlock>
        <Run>Row:</Run>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding SomeString}"></Run>
</TextBlock>
```

[MSDN Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't seem to be able to bind to the `Text` property of a `Run`?

Comment: @Phil Gan,  I've changed the sample code. Is this what you are looking for ?  Cheers.

Comment: @biju,  ya, you are correct. I overlooked the binding part.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Karthik: No I meant that this doesn't work. The `Text` property of a `Run` is not a `DependencyProperty` and so can't be bound to.

Comment: `Run.Text` *is* bindable starting in .NET 4.0, but this question has a tag of .NET-3.5.

Comment: @Phil, what @joe mentioned was correct.  I didn't realized that one.  One other suggestion I have for you is to write a small custom control which internally makes use of TextBlock.